# How to add table for database in lightswitch server

Tags: database, lightswitch-2013

I have to add a table for database in Light-switch server, when i click the add table, i can able to add only the fields name and its property in the table. How can i add values for the field? I have to add values for the Name and Order fields of a table. Can any one help me.

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Click to highlight the field you want to edit, and look for the Properties window. In properties, you should see Choice List, as long as you are looking at the Server perspective, and you are not looking at a Primary Key.